# How to find in joining tables Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, find

Well this is the problem. I have a table **'Store'** that is join to a table **'Product'**, so each Store (for example Wal-Mart) has a series of products: (coffee, milk, ketchup, etc.) I need to do a find that retrieves only 2 random **Stores**, with a condition that those **Stores** must have at least one product.

I am doing the Find like this:

```
$this->Store->find('all', array( 'conditions' => ...... , 'order' => 'rand()','limit' => 2));
```

But this find can retrieve a **Store** with no products.

I can't do the find in the table **Product**, because multiples products have the same Store and the random can result in the same Store twice.

Comment: Do the find in the Products table like you mentioned, and then filter to only get DISTINCT **Product.store_id**. This will filter out getting the same store twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the find in the Products table like you mentioned, and then filter to only get **DISTINCT** **store_id**'s. This will filter out getting the same store twice. Something similar to:

```
$this->Store->Product->find('all', array(
        'order'     => 'rand()',
        'limit'     => 2,
        'fields'    => array('DISTINCT(Store.id)')
    ));
```

Or just **Group By** `Store.id`:

```
$this->Store->Product->find('all', array(
        'order'     => 'rand()',
        'limit'     => 2,
        'group'     => 'Store.id'
    ));
```